# Is this aditional const on extern an UB?

Tags: c, constants, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, extern

I have the following:

```
//h.h file
#pragma once
struct A { int x; };

//a.c file
#include "h.h"
struct A* a;

//b.c
#include "h.h"
extern struct A* const a;
int main() {}
```

I added an extra `const` on `extern` declaration. Adding this `const` would be UB?

If It's not UB, doing like below inside `main` would be UB?

```
(*(struct A**)&a) = malloc(sizeof(struct A));
```

Comment: FWIW `#pragma once` is also bogus. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. From Annex J.2:

> - Two declarations of the same object or function specify types that are not compatible (6.2.7).

And 6.2.7 ¶2:

> All declarations that refer to the same object or function shall have compatible type; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

And 6.7.3 ¶10:

> For two qualified types to be compatible, both shall have the identically qualified version of a compatible type; the order of type qualifiers within a list of specifiers or qualifiers does not affect the specified type.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following compilation unit:

```
#include "h.h"
extern struct A* const a;
void externalFunction(void);
int myFunction(void)
{
  struct A *p1,*p2;
  p1 = a;
  externalFunction();
  p2 = a;
  return p2-p1;
}
```

The Standard would allow a compiler to assume, on the basis of the `const` directive, that the value of `a` would not be changed as a consequence of the call to `externalFunction`.  Note that it makes no effort to consider whether there might be advantages to allowing for the possibility that an external function might modify `a`.  For example, on some platforms, `a` might normally be write-protected, but an external function (perhaps written in another language) might be capable of disabling the write protection, modifying `a`, and then re-enabling the protection.  Whether it would be useful for an implementation to allow for such possibilities would depend upon the range of purposes for which an implementation claims to be suitable, which is something the Committee can't possibly know about, but which compiler writers should.